# Display problem on an Acer 7700GX

Tags: drivers, display, acer

i have just put ubuntu onto an old Acer 7700GX. it all looks lovely for a few minutes but then the desktop background goes blocky and the text goes a bit crazy. this doesn't seem to affect new windows that i open though.

I guess its a driver thing. any tips?

Answer (score 2):

The OP resolved the issue by installing Xubuntu

> i installed Xubuntu and my machine is now way quicker. I still get the glitch but have only had it once so far.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11521040&postcount=3